# gVisMotionChart gives issue with unique rows

Tags: r, googlevis

I am trying to use `gVisMotion` Chart but I get an error.

```
gg=gvisMotionChart(data, idvar='NY.GNP.PCAP.CD',   timevar='year',options=list())
 Error in gvisCheckMotionChartData(data, my.options) : 
 The data must have rows with unique combinations of idvar and timevar.
 Your data has 9982 rows, but idvar and timevar only define 6328 unique rows.
```

This is what I am doing

```
 dat = WDI(indicator='NY.GNP.PCAP.CD', country="all",start=1970, end=2016)
 l = dim(dat)
 #Subset countries
 data <- dat[2163:l[1],]
  gg=gvisMotionChart(data, idvar='NY.GNP.PCAP.CD', timevar='year',options=list())
```

and I get the error

> Error in gvisCheckMotionChartData(data, my.options) :   The data must
>   have rows with unique combinations of idvar and timevar.  Your data
>   has 9982 rows, but idvar and timevar only define 6328 unique rows.

```
 head(data)
 iso2c     country      NY.GNP.PCAP.CD year
2163    AF Afghanistan            630 2015
2164    AF Afghanistan            670 2014
2165    AF Afghanistan            730 2013
...
```

It is quite likely that `NY.GNP.PCAP.CD` & `year` have some repeating rows for different countries. Isn't it?

What am I doing wrong?  How can this be fixed?

Comment: shouldnt ``idvar='NY.GNP.PCAP.CD'`` be changed to ``idvar='country'``?

Comment: The intuition being that different countries (or even the same country) could have the same GNP over the course of different years -thats why you get that error. Running the code I pasted above works.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. Yes it works! You can answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idvar='NY.GNP.PCAP.CD'` should be changed to `idvar='country'`. The intuition being that different countries (or even the same country) could have the same GNP over the course of different years -thats why you get that error. Running this code works.

```
data <- dat[2163:l[1],]
  gg=gvisMotionChart(data, idvar='idvar='country'', timevar='year',options=list())
```